# C++ Explicitly using a function from an included headerfile in omnet++

Tags: c++, tcpclient, send, omnet++

I have a question about using the function "send" (which is defined in the headerfile winsock2.h) I included in by omnet++ class "Computer".
The function is not found because the compiler seems to only search for it in the class/module "Computer".

```
#include "Computer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>


#define NS_INADDRSZ  4
#define NS_IN6ADDRSZ 16
#define NS_INT16SZ   2


#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

Define_Module(Computer);



void Computer::initialize()
{
string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";  //IP Address of the server
int port = 59006;                //Listening port # on the server

//Initialize WinSock
WSAData data;
WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
if (wsResult != 0)
{
    cerr << "Can't start winsock, Err #" << wsResult << endl;
        return;
}

//Create Socket
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}
// Fill in a hint structure
sockaddr_in hint;
hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
hint.sin_port = htons(port);
//inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);
hint.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

// Connect to server
int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
   cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
   closesocket(sock);
   WSACleanup();
   return;
}

//Do-while loop to send and receive data
char buf[4096];
string userInput;

do
 {
    // Prompt the usedr for some text
    cout << "> ";
    getline(cin, userInput);

    if (userInput.size() > 0)  // Make sure the user has typed in something
    {
        // Send the text
        int sendResult = send(sock, userInput.c_str(), userInput.size() + 1, 0);
        if (sendResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
```

I get the error: no matching function for call to 'Computer::send(SOCKET&, const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string::size_type, int)'

Only the last part with "send" is relevant. The rest works fine.

Of course, "send" is not a function of "Computer" but of winsock2.h.
Does anyone know how I can clarify this in my code?

Problem is in Computer.h, Computer is a "cSimpleModule:

```
#ifndef __TCP_COMPUTER_H_
#define __TCP_COMPUTER_H_

#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

/**
* TODO - Generated class
*/
class Computer : public cSimpleModule
{
protected:
virtual void initialize();
virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
};

#endif
```

And cSimpleModule class has its own function "send".
(https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cSimpleModule.html)

Best regards,
Lukas

Comment: Does `Computer` have its own `send` method? This question would benefit greatly from being turned into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)--both _minimal_ by removing all the stuff that is presumably working fine and not relevant to your question, and _reproducible_ by giving people enough information to see what's going on.

Comment: To call out of the class, and reach a global function, you use `::send(parameters)`.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson: Yes, I was not precise. I added some background. However, BoP solved my problem! Thank you very much.

Comment: @BoP If a resolution has been achieved either OP or you should compose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a scoping problem, where a member function in `Computer` hid the global `send` function from Winsock. This can be resolved by an explicit scope resolution using `::`.

So, to call out of the class, and reach a global function, you use `::send(parameters)`.